# PHP - Help scraping content from web page using simplehtmldom

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to get contents marked with reed in images.

[The link of the logo with 200px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIwKq.png)

[The link of ground place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oZnp.png)

[The Capacity number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmoRP.png)

I have tried this so far

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
//Wikipedia page to parse
$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloa_Athletic_F.C.');

foreach($html->find('.label') as $element)
    echo $element->href  . "\n";
```

second code

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$aHtml = file('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloa_Athletic_F.C.');

foreach($aHtml as $id => $element):
  if( strpos($element, 'logo') ):
    echo $id .':' .htmlspecialchars($element) . "<br><br>\n";
  endif;
endforeach;
```

but i cant get the results i need.